# Inquiry submitted but not received

Tags: asp.net, email

can you help me on my site error on inquiry form.

Enquiry submitted! but inquiry email not received. please check below mentioned..

```
>SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
>client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
>client.EnableSsl = true;
>client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

>client.Port = 587;
>System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
>new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bookmark.ativs@gmail.com",
"********");
>client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
>client.Credentials = credentials;
>MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
>msg.From = new MailAddress("bookmark.ativs@gmail.com");
>msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("bookmark.ativs@gmail.com"));
>msg.Subject = "Enquiry";
>msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
>msg.Body = string.Format("<html><head></head><body><b>ENQUIRY<BR><hr><br> Name : >"+TextBox1 .Text +"<br> Email : "+TextBox2 .Text +"<br> Phone : "+TextBox3 .Text >+"<br>Course : "+DropDownList1 .SelectedValue+"<br> Degree :"+TxtDegree .Text +"<br> >Message : "+TextBox5 .Text +"</b></body>");
```

Comment: Inquiry is still not submitted in your code. is this code all that you have implemented for submitting inquiry? or you have more?

Comment: anyone help me ... i m waiting your response ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client.Send(msg); to complete the process.

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: and also you check this link - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/779810/Enquire-form-Error-The-SMTP-server-requires-a-secu?arn=0

Comment: Go to Settings and choose "Forwarding and POP/IMAP", in that select
"Enable POP for all mail". You should be good to send mail.